# How to fix: Adding value of checkboxes with different value for first two checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, syntax, addition

Attempting to Add together the value of a variety of check boxes based on the selection on the first two check boxes. The `Select` is used to represent a POST for a page and is the multiplier for `100kms` and `200kms` and the other check boxes. which gets shown at a daily rate without multiplying and a total with multiplying. I have a feeling it is either a syntax error or function call error.

I've tried to create a different set of functions to serve it's own purpose and inevitable add/ multiply things together. I've tried to change where the functions calls another such as `DisplayVals1` and `Calculate1`. My Fiddle is here for viewing. https://jsfiddle.net/shiataz12/mjnqth3L/83/

```
 $("#qr3").click(function() {
     var n3 = $( "input[name='checkbox1']:checked" ).length;
     if(n3) {
       Calculate1();
     }
     else {
       Calculate2();
     }
 });
```

Above snippet is what i tried to use to run the addition of extra check boxes to the total.

Comment: Hello and welcome. The jsFiddle does not run as it has many errors. The main issue is multiple checkboxes with the same ID qr3. The entire event will not fire in this case. Additionally, you can simply use $('id').checked to check the state of the checkbox.

Comment: could i then split it up into an array to add them in but how would i do a check and add for either value of `#qr1` or `#qr2`

Comment: So I've worked on it more and come to a new problem my fiddle here, can't change the value of the `200kms` from `100kms` https://jsfiddle.net/shiataz12/mjnqth3L/169/

Comment: First, change your first two checkboxes to radio buttons if you want them to be mutually exclusive

Comment: Much appreciated @Daryll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment suggestion id must be unique. You can checked check box is checked or not using `prop("checked", true);` like below. Your fiddle have error so I just remove other code and call function only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("input[name='checkbox1']").prop("checked") == true) {
    Calculate1();
  }
  $('input[name="checkbox1"]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="checkbox2"]').prop('checked', false);
  });
  if ($("input[name='checkbox2']").prop("checked") == true) {
    Calculate2();
  }
  $('input[name="checkbox2"]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop('checked', false);

  });
});


function Calculate1() {
  alert('calling Calculate1 function');
}

function Calculate2() {
  alert('calling Calculate2 function');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="mySelect">No. Days</label>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
  <option name="one" value="1">1</option>
  <option name="two" value="2">2</option>
  <option name="three" value="3">3</option>
  <option name="four" value="4">4</option>
  <option name="five" value="5" selected>5</option>
</select><br><br>
<label for="checkbox1">100kms</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="125" id="qr1" checked>111<br><br>
<label for="checkbox2">200kms</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="225" id="qr2">222<br><br>
<label for="checkbox3">Tyre</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="20" id="qr3"><br><br>
<label for="checkbox4">Glass</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="20" id="qr4"><br><br>
<label for="checkbox5">General</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" value="60" id="qr5" checked><br><br>
<label for="checkbox6">Third Party</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" value="80" id="qr6"><br><br> Daily :<span id="userdaily"> </span><br><br> Total :<span id="usertotal"> </span><br><br>
<input type="text" id="pricef1" name="pricef1" value="">
<input type="text" id="pricef2" name="pricef2" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your new question from your comments: There are 2 places where you have used kilo1 where you meant to use kilo2. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/oaxtz8q7/

Places such as

```
kms41 =  parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo1);
```

should be

```
kms41 =  parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo2);
```

Comment: wow such a minor mistake, thank you for pointing that out after taking the time to read through that mess.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the Extras `checkbox 3 - 6` will no add in, would i need to change the last if statements where `100kms` and `200kms` are checked on checking an `extra`?

Comment: You're welcome. Using developer tools (F12) I saw the error 'kilo1 is undefined' and simply searched for kilo1. I'm not sure what you mean that those checkboxes are not adding in.

Comment: No worries figured it out, posted my answer above.

Comment: As a thought what are you running your code with? Brackets or another?

Comment: I use VS Code IDE but I spend more time in Stack Overflow's inline code editor and [playcode.io](http://playcode.io) to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone Interested in this topic, i figured out the problem, although my code could be reduced somewhat i manage to get my fiddle working and will post it here for anyone to look at. The error was in the line `else if ($(($('input[name="checkbox2"]').prop("checked") == true) {` this  doesn't necessarily execute as the first statement come back false anyhow. That is what I think anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/shiataz12/Lo1yek2g/7/. and I added the code snippet if it's easier.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
    displayVals1();
  }
  if ($('input[name="checkbox2"]').prop("checked") == true) {
    displayVals2();
  }
});
$('input[name="checkbox1"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="checkbox2"]').prop('checked', false);
});
$('input[name="checkbox2"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop('checked', false);
});
$('input[name="checkbox5"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="checkbox6"]').prop('checked', false);
});
$('input[name="checkbox6"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="checkbox5"]').prop('checked', false);
});
$("#qr1").change(function() {

  //$("#qr1").prop('disabled', true);
  //$("#qr2").prop('disabled', false);
});
$("#qr2").change(function() {
  //$("#qr2").prop('disabled', true);
  //$("#qr1").prop('disabled', false);
});
$("#qr5").change(function() {
  $("#qr5").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#qr6").prop('disabled', false);
});
$("#qr6").change(function() {
  $("#qr6").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#qr5").prop('disabled', false);
});

function displayVals1() {
  Calculate1();
  var extras11 = 0;
  var extras12 = 0;
  var extra11a = 0;
  var extra12a = 0;
  var extra13a = 0;
  var extra14a = 0;
  var extra11b = 0;
  var extra12b = 0;
  var extra13b = 0;
  var extra14b = 0;
  var Multiplier = $("#mySelect").val();
  var kilo1 = $('input[id="qr1"]').val();
  var total11 = 0;
  var kms11 = 0;
  var fullTot11 = 0;
  var fullTot12 = 0;
  if ($("input[name='checkbox3']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra1a = $("input[name='checkbox3']").val();
    extra11a = parseInt(extra1a) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra11b = parseInt(extra1a);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox4']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra2a = $("input[name='checkbox4']").val();
    extra12a = parseInt(extra2a) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra12b = parseInt(extra2a);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox5']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra3a = $("input[name='checkbox5']").val();
    extra13a = parseInt(extra3a) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra13b = parseInt(extra3a);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox6']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra4a = $("input[name='checkbox6']").val();
    extra14a = parseInt(extra4a) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra14b = parseInt(extra4a);
  }
  extras11 = parseInt(extra11b) + parseInt(extra12b) + parseInt(extra13b) + parseInt(extra14b);
  extras12 = parseInt(extra11a) + parseInt(extra12a) + parseInt(extra13a) + parseInt(extra14a);
  total11 = parseInt(extras12);
  kms11 = parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo1);
  fullTot11 = parseInt(total11) + parseInt(kms11);
  fullTot12 = parseInt(extras11) + parseInt(kilo1);
  $("#pricef1").val(fullTot12);
  $("#pricef2").val(fullTot11);
}

function Calculate1() {
  var extras21 = 0;
  var extras22 = 0;
  var extra21a = 0;
  var extra22a = 0;
  var extra23a = 0;
  var extra24a = 0;
  var extra21b = 0;
  var extra22b = 0;
  var extra23b = 0;
  var extra24b = 0;
  var Multiplier = $("#mySelect").val();
  var kilo1 = $('input[id="qr1"]').val();
  var fullTot21 = 0;
  var fullTot22 = 0;
  var total21 = 0;
  var kms21 = 0;
  var total22 = 0;
  if ($("input[name='checkbox3']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra1b = $("input[name='checkbox3']").val();
    extra21a = parseInt(extra1b) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra21b1b = parseInt(extra1b);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox4']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra2b = $("input[name='checkbox4']").val();
    extra22a = parseInt(extra2b) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra22b = parseInt(extra2b);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox5']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra3b = $("input[name='checkbox5']").val();
    extra23a = parseInt(extra3b) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra23b = parseInt(extra3b);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox6']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra4b = $("input[name='checkbox6']").val();
    extra24a = parseInt(extra4b) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra24b = parseInt(extra4b);
  }
  extras21 = parseInt(extra21a) + parseInt(extra22a) + parseInt(extra23a) + parseInt(extra24a);
  extras22 = parseInt(extra21b) + parseInt(extra22b) + parseInt(extra22b) + parseInt(extra22b);

  total21 = parseInt(extras21);
  kms21 = parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo1);
  fullTot21 = parseInt(total21) + parseInt(kms21);
  fullTot22 = parseInt(kilo1) + parseInt(extras22);

  $("#usertotal").text('R ' + fullTot21 + '/day');
  $("#userdaily").text('R ' + fullTot22 + '/day');
}

function displayVals2() {
  Calculate2();
  var extras31 = 0;
  var extras32 = 0;
  var extra31a = 0;
  var extra32a = 0;
  var extra33a = 0;
  var extra34a = 0;
  var extra31b = 0;
  var extra32b = 0;
  var extra33b = 0;
  var extra34b = 0;
  var Multiplier = $("#mySelect").val();
  var kilo2 = $('input[id="qr2"]').val();
  var total31 = 0;
  var kms31 = 0;
  var fullTot31 = 0;
  var fullTot32 = 0;
  if ($("input[name='checkbox3']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra1c = $("input[name='checkbox3']").val();
    extra31a = parseInt(extra1c) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra31b = parseInt(extra1c);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox4']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra2c = $("input[name='checkbox4']").val();
    extra32a = parseInt(extra2c) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra32b = parseInt(extra2c);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox5']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra3c = $("input[name='checkbox5']").val();
    extra33a = parseInt(extra3c) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra33b = parseInt(extra3c);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox6']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra4c = $("input[name='checkbox6']").val();
    extra34a = parseInt(extra4c) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra34b = parseInt(extra4c);
  }
  extras31 = parseInt(extra31a) + parseInt(extra32a) + parseInt(extra33a) + parseInt(extra34a);
  extras32 = parseInt(extra31b) + parseInt(extra32b) + parseInt(extra33b) + parseInt(extra34b);
  total31 = parseInt(extras31);
  kms31 = parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo2);
  fullTot31 = parseInt(extras32) + parseInt(kilo2);
  fullTot32 = parseInt(total31) + parseInt(kms31);

  $("#pricef1").val(fullTot31);
  $("#pricef2").val(fullTot32);
}

function Calculate2() {
  var extras41 = 0;
  var extras42 = 0;
  var extra41a = 0;
  var extra42a = 0;
  var extra43a = 0;
  var extra44a = 0;
  var extra41b = 0;
  var extra42b = 0;
  var extra43b = 0;
  var extra44b = 0;
  var Multiplier = $("#mySelect").val();
  var kilo2 = $('input[id="qr2"]').val();
  var fullTot41 = 0;
  var fullTot42 = 0;
  var total41 = 0;
  var kms41 = 0;
  var total42 = 0;
  if ($("input[name='checkbox3']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra1d = $("input[name='checkbox3']").val();
    extra41a = parseInt(extra1d) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra41b = parseInt(extra1d);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox4']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra2d = $("input[name='checkbox4']").val();
    extra42a = parseInt(extra2d) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra42b = parseInt(extra2d);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox5']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra3d = $("input[name='checkbox5']").val();
    extra43a = parseInt(extra3d) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra43b = parseInt(extra3d);
  }
  if ($("input[name='checkbox6']").prop("checked") == true) {
    var extra4d = $("input[name='checkbox6']").val();
    extra44a = parseInt(extra4d) * parseInt(Multiplier);
    extra44b = parseInt(extra4d);
  }
  extras41 = parseInt(extra41a) + parseInt(extra42a) + parseInt(extra43a) + parseInt(extra44a);
  extras42 = parseInt(extra41b) + parseInt(extra42b) + parseInt(extra42b) + parseInt(extra42b);

  total41 = parseInt(extras41);
  kms41 = parseInt(Multiplier) * parseInt(kilo2);
  fullTot41 = parseInt(total41) + parseInt(kms41);
  fullTot42 = parseInt(kilo2) + parseInt(extras42);

  $("#usertotal").text('R ' + fullTot41 + '/day');
  $("#userdaily").text('R ' + fullTot42 + '/day');
}
$("#qr1").click(function() {
  displayVals1();
});
$("#qr2").click(function() {
  displayVals2();
});
$('input[name="checkbox3"]').click(function() {
  if (($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true)) {
    displayVals1();
  } else {
    displayVals2();
  }
});
$('input[name="checkbox4"]').click(function() {
  if (($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true)) {
    displayVals1();
  } else {
    displayVals2();
  }
});
$('input[name="checkbox5"]').click(function() {
  if (($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true)) {
    displayVals1();
  } else {
    displayVals2();
  }
});
$('input[name="checkbox6"]').click(function() {
  if (($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true)) {
    displayVals1();
  } else {
    displayVals2();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="mySelect">No. Days</label>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
  <option name="one" value="1">1</option>
  <option name="two" value="2">2</option>
  <option name="three" value="3">3</option>
  <option name="four" value="4">4</option>
  <option name="five" value="5" selected>5</option>
</select><br><br>
<label for="checkbox1">100kms</label>
<input type="radio" name="checkbox1" class="kilo" value="125" id="qr1" checked><br><br>
<label for="checkbox1">200kms</label>
<input type="radio" name="checkbox1" class="kilo" value="225" id="qr2"><br><br>
<label for="checkbox3">Tyre</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="20" id="qr3"><br><br>
<label for="checkbox4">Glass</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="20" id="qr4"><br><br>
<label for="checkbox5">General</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" value="60" id="qr5" checked><br><br>
<label for="checkbox6">Third Party</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" value="80" id="qr6"><br><br> Daily :<span id="userdaily"> </span><br><br> Total :<span id="usertotal"> </span><br><br>
<input tyep="text" id="pricef1" name="pricef1" value="">
<input tyep="text" id="pricef2" name="pricef2" value="">
```